# CouchApp paths are wrong after import

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I'm using CouchApp to push an existing html&javascript application. The application uses jquery and twitter bootstrap and it works perfectly fine from a regular web server / when opened locally.

(The application is basically a ready made app I bought and which I wish to redesign)

After I push the application (which is structured in many folders) I can't open it from couchdb since all the paths are "wrong".

My HTML files are under Page/PageType/Pagename.html so every css for example is accessed via ../../stylesheet/style.css but the URL can't be accessed when calling couchdb.

For example I have this page:

```
    http://127.0.0.1:5984/coreadmin/_design/coreadmin/pages%2fother%2fsign_up.html
```

Which is displayed in the browser but without style/js/images because the path is:

```
    http://127.0.0.1:5984/coreadmin/stylesheets/application.css (So _design/coreadmin is missing)
```

Is it possible to upload the project as is and make it work or do I have to go over all the files and fix the paths? (which means it will not work on any other web server...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the URL - by replacing the %2f to / everything everything is now working just fine.